# Barrio Theme 5.5.10 Main Menu submenu does not output list items

Tags: theming

I need help with the Barrio Theme submenus. I upgraded our site to 5.5.10 to discover the menu has stopped working. In my attempt to figure this out, I recreated a test site locally and installed a Drupal 9.5.5 legacy-project and barrio 5.5.10.

The submenu is not outputting the listing of the submenu. The documentation says all parents must be expandable and they are. I dont know the system is ignoring the menu items.

Any ideas?

Code that outputs:

```
<ul class="clearfix nav navbar-nav">
 <li class="nav-item">
    <a href="/legacy/" class="nav-link nav-link--legacy- is-active" data-drupal-link-system-path="<front>">Home</a>
  </li>
    <li class="nav-item menu-item--expanded dropdown">
    <a href="" title="EMTP Products " class="nav-link dropdown-toggle nav-link-" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">Products</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <a href="/legacy/products/emtp" title="EMTP Software for transient analysis" class="nav-link--legacy-products-emtp">EMTP</a>
              </li>
            <li class="dropdown-item menu-item--collapsed">
                    <a href="" title="Modules to extend EMTP" class="nav-link-">Modules</a>
              </li>
        </ul>
  </li>
```

[image: Admin Blocks Main Menu Settings]

[image: Main Menu dropdown]

[image: No Sub Menu]

Greatly appreciated if anyone has an idea

Comment: Have you edited the menu block and checked the settings there? As that also has controls on how many levels to show

Comment: Hi @unusedspoon, I have the settings as 'unlimited' but it does not work. I will try Shandesh's answer to see if it works. The issue is not just bootstrap actually because i switched to 'olivero' with the same problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First make sure you have set the **Number of levels to display** as required(3 in your case). You can do it by visiting `admin/structure/block/manage/Your_Theme_Machine_Name`.

[image]

2. Then check the **Flyout style main menu** option in your theme settings under `Components > Navbar behaviour`. You can do it by visiting `admin/appearance/settings/Your_Theme_Machine_Name`.

[image]

**Explanation**:
The third level items are not showing because according the maintainer of the contrib theme bootstrap_barrio, that's how it is designed. Bootstrap Navbar by default supports only 2 levels of dropdown menu. You can read more about this issue here.
https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio/issues/3133347#comment-14021486

Comment: Hi Sandesh, Thank you for this, I had 'unlimited' selected and switched to '3' but with both Olivero and bootstrap the third level does not output or render the submenu in the html. I am suspicious that it is a drupal core vs themes?  I also have the nav bar set to flyout.

Comment: Actually the number of levels was still 2 so I set it to 3 and now it works! thank you!!